# split slider Items in multiple rows

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I hope you can give me a hint:
A slider of category images with a url link will be displayed on a start page. Just 4 images per row have to be displayed. How can do that? I cant see the solution. :-/

The website uses i.a. react.js.

```
<div className="middle-section">
          {categories && categories.length > 0 &&
            <div className="categories-wrapper">
              <Slider multi>
                {
                  categories.map((model) => {
                    return <CategoryItem key={model.ID} model={model}
                      url={urlGenerator.get({ page: 'category', id: model.FriendlyID, name: decodeStringForURL(model.Name) })} />
                  }
                  )
                }
              </Slider>
            </div>
          }
```

The element CategoryItem looks like below:

```
const CategoryItem = ({ model, url, className }) => {
  if (!model) {
    return <div className="category-item" />
  }

  const imageUrl = model.ImageUrl ? model.ImageUrl : require(`$assets/images/default.png`)
  return (
    <div>
    <Link to={url}>
      <a className={`category-item ${className || ''}`} data-qaautomationinfo={model.FriendlyID}>
        <div className="image-wrapper">
          <img src={imageUrl} />
        </div>
        <div className="category-name">
          <HTMLLinesEllipsis style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }} unsafeHTML={model.Name} maxLine={2} basedOn='words' />
        </div>
      </a>
    </Link>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The CSS of CategoryItem looks like below:

```
.category-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: var(--text-size-label);
}
```

I really cant see it.

Hope you can help me guys.

Thx a lot!

Comment: Please add a working code example (Even without react - Your issue is more related to CSS). Very hard to answer your issue like this. In general, this is the property handle lines: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap

Comment: I got it. It's related to CSS. I handled it with the following:

`categorycat-item:nth-child(4):after { 
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre; 
}`

And it work for me. Thx a lot!